# Installing & running modules in Python 3 (Beginner)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, importerror, moviepy

I am very new to the world of coding, so I will try to provide as much information as i can regarding to my question.

Essentially, I wanted to install a module (moviepy) for Python 3. The site were I found the module suggested I use pip to unpack and install the module, so I did.

In my terminal, I entered `pip install moviepy` and pip proceeded to unpack and install my module, yay!

I then went over to my IDLE to see if the module would import, `import moviepy`, but received this error:

> ImportError: No module named 'moviepy'

Huh? I thought I had just installed moviepy?

Upon further investigation, the module appears to have been written to my Python 2.7 site-packages folder and not my in Python 3 site-packages folder.

So my question is: How can I get my module to install to Python 3?

The modules website says that it is compatible with Python 3.

Im assuming this is a file path issue of some kind, but i don't know where to begin.

I'm currently using a OS X Yosemite version 10.10.2, Python 2.7.6, Python 3.5.0

Any help or comments are greatly appreciated here!
Help the n00b!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using python in linux you must run pip with python3:

```
python3 -m pip install moviepy
```

according to python official doc :

> On Linux, Mac OS X and other POSIX systems, use the versioned Python
>   commands in combination with the -m switch to run the appropriate copy
>   of pip:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

Comment: I think just `pip3 install moviepy` is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Since pip itself is written in python , you could simply run the following in your terminal:

```
/path/to/python3 /usr/bin/pip install foo
```

**More info:**

To install pip, securely download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Run the following (which may require administrator access):

```
/path/to/python3 get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below version of moviepy

`pip install moviepy==0.2.3.5`